# Firma CADES-T Java8

Tags: java, java-8, soap, certificado

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Java (versión 8) que llamará a un WS de SOAP. Tiene el siguiente parámetro de entrada;

```
 <![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:mensajeWS xmlns:ns2="https://wslexnet.webservices.lexnet/3.27">
    <solicitudLoginServiciosGeneral>
        <idAplicacion>MIID</idAplicacion>
        <firmaAplicacionFIRMA</firmaAplicacion>
    </solicitudLoginServiciosGeneral>
</ns2:mensajeWS>]]>
```

Donde **firmaAplicacion** se obtendrá de la siguiente manera:

1. El valor de **idAplicacion** se pasa a *SHA-256*
2. Una vez que se obtiene el valor en *SHA-256* se realiza la firma en *CADES-T*
3. Por ultimo se pasa a *Base64*.

Se cómo se obtiene los pasos 1 y 3. Pero la duda es la firma en *CADES-T* (Sé que tiene algo que ver con la librería **java.security.cert.X509Certificate**) y dispongo de un certificado público (con extensión *.cer*) y uno privado (con extensión *.p12* y su contraseño) pero no encuentro la manera de desarrollarlo. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

Cualquier duda o aclaración decídmelo y lo reviso.

Muchas gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo.